# How do i update R on Cent OS?

Tags: r, centos

I am having issues finding a way to Update R on CentOS.

I  ran "yum remove R" and returned a successful message. But when i type R it still loads up the R environment.

Do i need to remove it another way first, before updating? I'm Running R Version 2.15.2

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just run the following to update your R distribution.

```
yum update R
```

Further details are needed if you are having additional problems.  Or try removing all the R components separately as noted by @TARehman.

**Note** - this all assumes you don't need `sudo` privileges otherwise you would need to make some administrative requests if you aren't the owner of the machine.

Comment: This did not work on my Centos server

Answer (score 2):

On our CentOS machines, R involves a few different things. Running `yum list installed | grep R` returns:

```
R.x86_64                                  2.15.2-1.el5                 installed
R-core.x86_64                             2.15.2-1.el5                 installed
R-devel.x86_64                            2.15.2-1.el5                 installed
```

I'd suggest that you do `sudo yum remove` on all of them if you're concerned that you're not getting the newest version.